# Image chosen from gallery disappears from Imageview after application closes

Tags: android, imageview, filechooser

I hope you can help me with my simple problem. I am trying to select an image to display on my Imageview from my gallery, It works but the thing is, It disappears after I close my app. Please check the code that I found below.

```
iv=(ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.profpic);
            iv.setOnClickListener(this);



    private void showFileChooser() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); 
        intent.setType("image/*"); 
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

        try {
            startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a File to Upload"),
                    FILE_SELECT_CODE);
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            // Potentially direct the user to the Market with a Dialog
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please install a File Manager.", 
                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case FILE_SELECT_CODE:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // Get the Uri of the selected file 
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                iv.setImageURI(uri);
                Log.d(TAG, "File Uri: " + uri.toString());
               }
            break;
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

and my xml:

```
  <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profpic"
        android:layout_width="113dp"
        android:layout_height="113dp"
        android:paddingRight="1dp"
        android:src="@drawable/propic" />
```

I am new to android development and any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: When the activity is destroyed, so is the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you upload the image , it won't retain their forever. You need to keep the path of the selected image in [Sqlite database](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CCYQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Freference%2Fandroid%2Fdatabase%2Fsqlite%2Fpackage-summary.html&ei=WPX_U8jEOse9uASy_IDACA&usg=AFQjCNF8aHy__4EKyivNW9vK1dQKVVb5ag&sig2=sNaC3PlyE3K8Wjxl9Ey-Gw&bvm=bv.74115972,d.c2E) or a [SharedPreference](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Freference%2Fandroid%2Fcontent%2FSharedPreferences.html&ei=RvX_U4HoDs29ugSnkoKoCA&usg=AFQjCNFyaMlF7pqBKbWPbXr7H1Wg4gKaoA&sig2=DPWQEMW27fwnNNkLj9eScA&bvm=bv.74115972,d.c2E). Then on launching your activity you need to use the image path to load in to the `ImageView`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will try to research more about this.